# Could not access my domain after reinstall apache2

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, wordpress

I have 3 WordPress installed on my Ubuntu in `/var/www/html` directory. There was no issue from last two years. 
But recently while I am installing another script in the same directory, I had to purge and reinstall the apache2.

And after that, I am unable to access my all websites. It says "Unable to connect"

When I entered IP address it's showing the Apache server home page instead of 3 directory page that was shown before.

I have tried to restart the Apache server and its running well but still no result.

- www.misources.com
- www.trackerplanet.com
- www.mypan.co.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not configured your webserver to accept TLS traffic, commonly known as https.

If we check the reply for the website, using `curl -I` we see that http://www.misources.com redirects to http**s**://www.misources.com:

```
$ curl -I www.misources.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2019 13:38:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.misources.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

If we try to follow that redirect, like your browser would, we get a connection denied:

```
$ curl -I https://www.misources.com/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.misources.com port 443: Connection refused
```

The same is the case for the rest of your domains as well. You have probably not loaded the ssl module. I suggest you try `sudo a2enmod ssl`, and restart your webserver.

You should probably check your configuration as well.

However, you should ***not*** have to purge apache to fix any issues with a script. That's nonsensical. The Apache installation does not interfere with your content directories.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It works but now I am getting "This site can’t provide a secure connection" "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" on the browser. Still unable to access my site. Please reply for the next suggestion

Comment: @IrfanHabib See my updated answer. In short, you have to recreate the configuration as it was. Given your level of knowledge, I would generally suggest to stick with managed hosting...

Comment: Hello again. after i run   "a2ensite default-ssl" its showing the apache server home page instead my wp site without ssl

Comment: Your TLS config is ***BROKEN***. Don't go around blindly running commands. Configure it correctly. It's laid out in the linked documentation above - or you can make a new question about it. As it is now, it returns an invalid certificate, so you have to configure it with correct certificates.

Comment: what if I delete or revoke ssl? anyway I am using letsencrypt ssl

Comment: Then you'd have to reconfigure your site(s) to not redirect. But not offering TLS today is a bad idea, and may impact your google rankings.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed it with the "a2enmod php7.2" command. Now I can access my site without any configuration on ssl. I just renew the certificate. That's it. Anyway, a huge thanks from my heart.